with the latest Angular ESbuild, constructor.name to get the component name in runtime no longer works
with the latest Angular ESbuild, constructor.name to get the component name in runtime no longer works
Is there a different way to get the component name?
Thank you.

What exactly no longer works? What do you get ?

constructor.name gives _a1 ... _a2... etc, but not the component name

During the optimization phase, angular will mangle the class names (wether with the esbuild builder or the webpack builder).
This is expected and you should rely on the class name.
You likely didn't have any optimization enabled before.
